# No URL Access through batchfile executed from Windows Service

Tags: c#, url, service, batch-file, signtool

I'm signing executables through a Windows Service. This service creates a batch-file, in which the actual Sign command is:

```
cd D:\wmt_sign\Signer\Tools
signtool sign /f "D:\codesign\cert\Certificate.pfx" /p MyPass /t "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /d "zxz" /du "http://www.testurl.com"  "D:\codesign\Sign\Request307\filetobesigned.exe">>"D:\codesign\log\signlog\Request\SignLogReport.txt"
```

1. When I execute the batch command from the machine directly, no problem, everything works fine
2. When I execute the Sign command direclty from commanline, no problem everything works
3. when I execute the batchfile in code (process.startinfo....etc ) the timestamp-url cannot be reached! (error is "The specified timestamp server could not be reached.")

The service runs under Local System Account, there is a firewall, but this one is open for outwards traffic.

I have no clue at all....

Answer (score -1):

The LocalSystem account, by default, does not have any rights to access the network. You should use the Network Service acount instead. Even then, if any of the URLs you are trying to access require authentication, it may stil not work. It that case you may need to create a domain account for the service to run under or impersonate.

Comment: Too bad, even the Network Service Account doesn't work here.. Will have to check with a domain admin tomorrow. As I understood, this machine is not in a domain.

Comment: Set up the service to run as whatever account to you are logging into the box as. If it works then you know its a security issue for sure.

Comment: 'Local System' account is a privileged account and has access to all system resources, including the network (unless the account is artificially restricted from using them). You have confused it with 'Local Service'.